# How to get html page displayed in swagger UI (flask)

Tags: flask, swagger-ui, openapi

I have used apispec and flask-swagger-ui with flask.

The flask route returns a html page but on swagger UI I could only see the html code not the actual page.

Is there any way to get the html page displayed on swagger UI.

the flask code along with the APIspec documentation

[image: the flask code along with the APIspec documentation]

swagger UI response

[image: swagger UI response]

expected response

[image: expected response]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenAPI describes the text/code response your API will return. Swagger UI is correctly displaying the body of your response, not how that response will be interpreted and displayed by a particular consumer of your API (in this case a web browser). What you are trying to do is outside the intended scope of this tool. See [this issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1748) in which the developers rejected this idea for reasons of security.

### Alternative:

Use the `description` property to include a link to additional documentation that includes images or screenshots of what this response would look like.

Comment: Okay, got it so swagger does not have this feature because of security concerns.